# Error:Failed to resolve: wearable

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I have an existing project and when I try to add a wear module to it, the error below is shown. When I create a new project with a wear module it's working.

> Error:Failed to resolve: wearable

and

> project depends of com.google.android.support:wearable:2.3.0 so it must also depend com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.3.0

**error screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Are you by any chance using a different version of the build tools (buildToolVersion in your build.gradle file) when you create a new project compared to when you add a module to your existing project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a provided like this

```
...
provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.3.0'
...
```

Also check that your project level build.gradle has the google repository, I think some wearable libs now come from google rather than jcenter.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
}
```